# EOFError: end of file reached -- all js specs are crashing Capybara with an older Chrome driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara

Capybara using Chrome driver with setup:

spec_helper

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

I appear to be getting

```
 EOFError:
   end of file reached
```

On *all* of my Javascript tests when I run them with chrome driver.

This appears to have began on or around Oct 27, 2016

Running with poltergeist they work fine.

• also when they crash they appear to open multiple instances of chrome which hang (but do not exit) see http://screencast.com/t/Worwl9d6Iuhr screenshot example

• these appear to affect only my javascript specs (:js => true in Capybara)

• Rebooting my machine did not solve the problem

• My Chrome Mac OS X is currently at 54.0.2840.71

• I'm not sure when sub-sub-point version 71 got released since of course Chrome doesn't tell you or even seem to have it available in some kind of update history. The public information says sub-point version 54.0.2840 was released 2016-10-12 but it doesn't specify when sub-sub-point version 71 was released

• I can reproduce the effect on both my code on master, as well, I have a specific memory of running these specs with Chrome driver earlier in this week, so I am strongly suspecting that Chrome did a sub-sub-point release here and broke this.

if anyone else can confirm I would appreciate it. otherwise, if I find a local problem, I will post answer here.

• Capybara 2.7.1

• selenium-webdriver 2.53.0

• I located the Chromedriver executable in my machine at `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` [is this the right one -- I seem to have an older one in `/Users/jason/bin/chromedriver` ?]

`$ which chromedriver
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

`$ /usr/local/bin/chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b)`

Comment: also when they crash they appear to open multiple instances of chrome which hang (but do not exit) see http://screencast.com/t/Worwl9d6Iuhr screenshot example

Comment: Make sure you're running the latest chromedriver. 2.25 as of now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upgrading Chrome Driver to 2.25 solved the issue

to do so via brew

```
$ brew unlink chromedriver
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.20... 1 symlinks removed
$ brew install chromedriver
==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.25/chromedriver_mac6
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Caveats
To have launchd start chromedriver now and restart at login:
  brew services start chromedriver
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  chromedriver
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.25: 4 files, 10.3M, built in 7 seconds
```

Comment: This is spot on; there's a similar solution on the [capybara mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-capybara/YyuolCN182o)

Comment: If chromedriver isn't upgrading to the version you expect, try running `brew update` to fetch the newest version of Homebrew and all formulae, then try `brew upgrade chromedriver`

Comment: @NickTomlin-- Yea that's me cross-posting like mad cross-posting bug-hunting maniac.

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps someone. I recently got this error when I was using capybara/poltergeist on a specific port (`., then I had a crashed test process still listening on a specific port.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rbenv, you can upgrade the chromedriver using brew than copy the executable :

for example, I'm using ruby 2.4.1:

```
$ cp /usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.30/bin/chromedriver $HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/
$ chmod +x $HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/chromedriver
```

thank you